# Duhamel's Principle question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to prove the following form of Duhamel's principle, but don't know how to...
Can you help me please?

Let u(x,t) be the solution of the following initial-boundary value problem for the nonhomogeneous wave equation: (*)
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}= f(x,t)\\ 
u(x,0)=0\\ 
u_{t}(x,0)=0
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Let $w(x,t;\tau)$ be the solution to:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
w_{tt}-w_{xx}= 0\\ 
w(x,t=0)=0\\ 
w_{t}(x,t=0)=f(x,\tau)
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Show that then:

$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t}w(x,t-\tau;\tau)d\tau$ is the solution to (*).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed proof can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Inhomogeneous_wave_equation_in_one_dimension.